# Avoid http content stored on s3 bucket gets mangled in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have copied a set of gzip-ed log files into s3 bucket created with content-type "text/html" and content-encoding as gzip for this to be viewed on a browser with public http access set on the object.

The command used:

```
aws s3 cp file.gz s3://test-bucket-xyz --acl public-read --cache-control public --content-type "text/plain" --content-encoding "gzip"
```

Here is the link to the [logfile](https://test-bucket-xyz.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/_sys-info.log.gz) which is all mangled when viewed with the browser (google-chrome).

I'd want to view the output as follows:

```
---> lscpu:
 Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 58
Model name:            Intel Xeon E3-12xx v2 (Ivy Bridge, IBRS)
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               2499.998
BogoMIPS:              4999.99
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
```

The same issue not seen when the read from a apache. how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the file is plain text, not HTML. Give it a Content-Type of `text/plain`, and it'll display as intended in a browser.

Comment: I've tried setting this to "text/plain" as suggested now, still the same.

Comment: @askb Force a reload. The old headers may be cached by your browser.